# Bot stopped responding with self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I used pyTelegrambotAPI, cherrypy as webserver, update method webhook, self signed ceritficate and tonight after six month working without any problem 2 of my bots stop responding.

When I use command:

https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/getwebhookinfo 
the result is

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://MY.IP.ADRESS/MYTOKEN/","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":16853,"last_error_date":1518617645,"last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}}

so it's say that error with SSL, then I tried to make a new self-signed certificate and used command

> curl -F "url=https://MY.IP.ADRESS" -F "certificate=@C:\Users\007\Desktop\bin\webhook_cert5.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botMYTOKEN/setWebhook

answer is

> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

but after 10 seconds its certificate verify failed. Are telegram block self-signed certificates? Or I did something wrong?

Comment: I guess when I set webhook from curl with **@** symbol before full path of my self signed certificate Telegram see it and everything fine, but when I run my web server Telegram thinking that my certificate from some CA and can not verify it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer.

I was right in comment above, if you curl request return **Webhook was set** and when you start bot you see the error **certificate verify failed** you just need **@** symbol before your path to certificate on your web server, as example `bot.set_webhook(url=config.WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + config.WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, certificate=open("@" + config.WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))` (it's cherrypy web).